# Link static library using CMake

Tags: linker, cmake, static-linking

I cannot get the library `${static_library}` to statically link using CMake. I have tried hard coding the path and as far as I'm aware `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` should link this in automatically.

```
ADD_LIBRARY(libraryA STATIC ${source_files})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(libraryA debug ${static_library})
```

There is a sub project that links `libraryA` later in the build

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(testA ${test_sources}) 
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testA libraryA)
```

which has ${static_library} correctly linked in but I need `${static_library}` to be directly linked into `libraryA`.

Comment: What does the project structure look like and what error messages are you getting? Could it be that you are not compiling in debug mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot link libraries into libraries directly.

Some compilers allow you to do this (e.g. MS Visual Studio has an option), but others don't, which is why CMake also won't allow it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347235/linking-a-static-boost-build-into-a-static-library-under-vs2012-win32-64/18351904#18351904) for what your options are to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE lib_name${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
```

I have `libpq.a` and `libpq.so` (postgres) and with this solution it links to the static library so I can execute `my_target` on a clean OS.